# How to implement Server to Client Communication with a REST Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, cloud, ejb-3.0, resteasy

We have a requirement in which the server need to send some information to Desktop client Application. Both the applications are built over Java. A Wildfly server residing on a Cloud environment hosts the Server App and it supports REST requests over HTTP. The client application is a standalone Java application and it communicate to server using REST requests. Can anyone suggest which is the best strategy to implement this?

Comment: You can solve server to client communication using WebSockets or JMS.

Comment: Thanks... We used WebSockets for implementing the same.